# Which programming languages require dependency injection frameworks?

Tags: dependency-injection

Which programming languages, by design, require a dependency injection framework? I know Java does, but does Common Lisp or Smalltalk?

Comment: None. Not even Java. You can *choose* to use one, but it's not needed by any language that I know of.

Comment: To extend: **no** programming language (I know of) **requires** any framework. However, some, like Java and C#, are not very useful without one, such as the .NET Framework (differentiating from the CLR).

Answer (score 1):

IMHO any language where two different components talks to each other ***CAN USE*** dependency injection.